# displaying <li> elements in columns

Tags: c#, html, webforms

I have a certain amount of topics that I want to display on page load in columns next to each other. I tried using  the modulus operator to achieve this but instead the topics is displayed in one long list still.

How can I display these elements in columns next to one another?

This is what I have tried so far.

```
int rows = 50;

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            if (i % 9 == 0)
            {
                topicGenerator.InnerHtml += "<div class='topicGenSpacing'><ul>";
            }
            topicGenerator.InnerHtml += "<li>topic</li>";
            if (i % 9 == 8)
            {
                topicGenerator.InnerHtml += "</ul></div>";
            }
        }


<div class="topicList">
            <img src="Images/humanBig.jpg" alt="Health and Safety" />
            <div id="topicGenerator" runat="server">

             </div>

            <img src="Images/safetyBig.jpg" alt="Health and Safety" />


            <img src="Images/educationBig.jpg" alt="Health and Safety" />

        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to style your `li` as `display: inline;`.

The `li` is an element having default `display` as `block` which means the list elements (`li`) will appear one below the other (your present case).

Answer (score 1):

The question is not totally clear to me, but you can use `float` in CSS

```
float:left;
```

So, to use this with your code, you could do:

```
        {
            topicGenerator.InnerHtml += "<div class='topicGenSpacing'><ul>
        }
        topicGenerator.InnerHtml += "<li>topic</li>";
        if (i % 9 == 8)
        {
            topicGenerator.InnerHtml += "</ul></div>";
        }
```

and the CSS is

```
.topicGenSpacing
{
    float:left;
}
```

As an aside, you can use use quote marks if you escape them to not need to rely on single quotes. EG

```
<div class='topicGenSpacing'>
```

becomes

```
<div class=\"topicGenSpacing\">
```

which will translate to

```
<div class="topicGenSpacing">
```

Comment: `.topicGenSpacing` class should be used there instead of new `.menu`